# Are Chechen мукадахка /mukdahka/ "rat" and Armenian մուկ /muk/ cognate?

Tags: armenian, caucasian-languages

1. Are Chechen мукдахка /mukdahka/ "rat" and Armenian մուկ /muk/ cognate?
2. Are Chechen херси /**h**ersi/ "piglet" and Latin **p**orcus "pig" cognate?
   I know that IE "p" turned into "h" in Armenian **p**ater / **h**ayr հայր "father", **p**urgo / **h**ur հուր "fire". Could Chechen hersi be a borrowing from proto-armenian?
   Note: IE ḱ turned into s in Armenian her**s**i / por**c**us

Comment: Not cognates, but possibly Caucasian substratum words.

Comment: @fdb Armenian muk is almost certainly native. It's pretty much exactly the expected reflex of PIE *múh₂s. The only trickiness is why Classical Armenian has an n in mukn, but that's not exactly difficult as plenty of Classical Armenian words have an additional -n coming from the accusative

Comment: Looks like the case.